# AS3 - Trace - Click button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, trace

I am trying to click on a button and trace out a number "1" onto the stage/same scene.

I have this code:

```
 button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickReaction1);
 function myClickReaction1 (e:MouseEvent):void{
 trace("1");
 }
```

BUT it traces onto the output of flash and not onto the scene.

please help

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`trace("1");` will go to the output panel it is intended for debugging.

If you want to see something on the stage, you will need to create a `TextField` and set it's `text` property to whatever you want.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickReaction1);

function myClickReaction1 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.text = "1";
    addChild(tf);
}
```

Comment: It is just the name of the variable, could be any valid identifier name.

Comment: I have got it to show '1' on the stage BUT it goes into the top corner not in the text field where I want it to go?

Comment: You have to set the `x` and `y` of the `TextField` to position it wherever you want.

Comment: ok perfect that works but..one more thing Bascially I have a picture of a phone and the user has to click each number (button) to dial a number and thats why i wanted the number to be on the scene.. but now they cannot click on the button twice?

Comment: If there is a button under the TextField you need to set `mouseEnabled` to false on the TextField. You might alsow want to set `selectable` to false.

Comment: no button under text field its just placed in the scene but need the user to press it more than once however it shows more than once but on top of the other one? (if that makes any sense)