# How to debug If and Else statements in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, variable-assignment

My game is a drag and drop game where you have to dress up a character. What I need help with is that every time I would go to click finish, it would go straight to frame 12 (try again screen).

I am unsure as to how I can make it so that when all pieces are in the correct place and I click finish, it would take the user to frame 11 (Congratulations screen) and when the pieces aren't in the correct position, it would take the user to frame 12 (try again screen).

```
//Menu Button
menubtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(5);
}

//Not sure what this means
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EntFrame);
    function EntFrame(e:Event) :void
{


  //there are a total of 9 pieces (hair,shirt,shorts, leftglove,rightglove,leftsock,rightsock,rightboot,leftboot)
//from hair to left boot the code is just copied and pasted.)

    //Hair
hairmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_13);

function fl_ClickToDrag_13(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    hairmc.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_13);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_13(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    hairmc.stopDrag();
}
if (targethairmc.hitTestObject(hairmc.hair_mc))

{
    hairmc.x = 368.05;
    hairmc.y = 71.70;

}


//Left Boot
leftbootmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_23);

function fl_ClickToDrag_23(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    leftbootmc.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_23);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_23(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    leftbootmc.stopDrag();
}
if (targetleftbootmc.hitTestObject(leftbootmc.leftboot_mc))

{
    leftbootmc.x = 310.30;
    leftbootmc.y = 461.55;
}


finishbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (shirtmc.x == 365.95 && shirtmc.y == 208.60 && leftglovemc.x == 239.45 && leftglovemc.y == 160.15 && leftsockmc.x == 333.05 && leftsockmc.y == 411.25 && leftbootmc.x == 310.30 && leftbootmc.y == 461.55 && hairmc.x == 368.05 && hairmc.y == 71.70 && pantsmc.x == 367.05 && pantsmc.y == 311.25 && rightbootmc.x == 426.80 && rightbootmc.y == 461.55 && rightsockmc.x == 405.95 && rightsockmc.y == 411.25 && rightglovemc.x == 496.95 && rightglovemc.y == 157.65){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EntFrame);
        gotoAndStop(11);
    }else {
        gotoAndStop (12);
    }

}
```

Whenever I click the finish button,when the pieces are and are not in the correct position, or the menu button (which takes me back to a screen where i can select from 3 games,it brings up a message in the output section saying:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Ronaldo_fla::MainTimeline/EntFrame()
```

The buttons still work, they go to the frames that they are intended for, but the message keeps duplicating and it causes the game to lag and slow down.

Here is a picture showing the message that pops up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRP6b.png

Comment: I've added advice on your other post, but please let me know how you get on here. In relation to the debugging I've suggested, please add the results of that to this post.

Comment: @halfer Whenever I click the finish button, it ignores my if and jumps to the else statement. fl_MouseClickHandler_2 is the finish button but I used a code snippet and tried to add some of my own code into it but it doesn't seem to work. I am also a beginner and don't know to much about actionscript. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this line is in error:

```
if (shirtmc.x == 365.95 && shirtmc.y == 208.60 && leftglovemc.x == 239.45 && leftglovemc.y == 160.15 && leftsockmc.x == 333.05 && leftsockmc.y == 411.25 && leftbootmc.x == 310.30 && leftbootmc.y == 461.55 && hairmc.x == 368.05 && hairmc.y == 71.70 && pantsmc.x == 367.05 && pantsmc.y == 311.25 && rightbootmc.x == 426.80 && rightbootmc.y == 461.55 && rightsockmc.x == 405.95 && rightsockmc.y == 411.25 && rightglovemc.x == 496.95 && rightglovemc.y == 157.65){
```

To start with, that's not very readable, and that may be hiding an issue from you that you would otherwise spot. I would assume ActionScript will let you line-wrap - would you try this amendment in your code first?

```
if (
    shirtmc.x == 365.95 && shirtmc.y == 208.60 &&
    leftglovemc.x == 239.45 && leftglovemc.y == 160.15 &&
    leftsockmc.x == 333.05 && leftsockmc.y == 411.25 &&
    leftbootmc.x == 310.30 && leftbootmc.y == 461.55 &&
    hairmc.x == 368.05 && hairmc.y == 71.70 &&
    pantsmc.x == 367.05 && pantsmc.y == 311.25 &&
    rightbootmc.x == 426.80 && rightbootmc.y == 461.55 &&
    rightsockmc.x == 405.95 && rightsockmc.y == 411.25 &&
    rightglovemc.x == 496.95 && rightglovemc.y == 157.65
){
```

OK: one or more of those 18 conditions is failing where you do not expect it to. One would assume that ActionScript gives you some choices on how to debug this:

- Set a breakpoint on this `if` line and carefully inspect the value of each variable when the breakpoint is triggered;
- Echo out variables to a file or a console;
- Comment out clauses until the problematic ones are found (see below).

I suspect using this technique you will identify what the problem is.

---

"Commenting out" is a handy debugging trick to hide bits of code from the computer until you are ready to run them. Temporarily, change the code to this:

```
if (
    true
    //shirtmc.x == 365.95 && shirtmc.y == 208.60 &&
    //leftglovemc.x == 239.45 && leftglovemc.y == 160.15 &&
    //leftsockmc.x == 333.05 && leftsockmc.y == 411.25 &&
    //leftbootmc.x == 310.30 && leftbootmc.y == 461.55 &&
    //hairmc.x == 368.05 && hairmc.y == 71.70 &&
    //pantsmc.x == 367.05 && pantsmc.y == 311.25 &&
    //rightbootmc.x == 426.80 && rightbootmc.y == 461.55 &&
    //rightsockmc.x == 405.95 && rightsockmc.y == 411.25 &&
    //rightglovemc.x == 496.95 && rightglovemc.y == 157.65
){
```

Your first task is to ensure that the clause then runs, since the `true` will always cause it to run. Next, try this:

```
if (
    shirtmc.x == 365.95 && shirtmc.y == 208.60 //&&
    //leftglovemc.x == 239.45 && leftglovemc.y == 160.15 &&
    //leftsockmc.x == 333.05 && leftsockmc.y == 411.25 &&
    //leftbootmc.x == 310.30 && leftbootmc.y == 461.55 &&
    //hairmc.x == 368.05 && hairmc.y == 71.70 &&
    //pantsmc.x == 367.05 && pantsmc.y == 311.25 &&
    //rightbootmc.x == 426.80 && rightbootmc.y == 461.55 &&
    //rightsockmc.x == 405.95 && rightsockmc.y == 411.25 &&
    //rightglovemc.x == 496.95 && rightglovemc.y == 157.65
){
```

Notice that I have commented out the `&&` on the first line, so that the statement still makes sense. OK, so try that. If that works, do the next line, and if it fails (e.g. with an error or the `else` section triggers) find out why. Carry on uncommenting lines until you find a problem.

Comment: I have done as you said above and it's still not listening to my if, else statements. I have checked each location with previous typed up locations and still nothing. I snap the pieces into the locations listed above and it still doesn't want to listen. But now multiple messages pop up in my output box saying: **TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at MethodInfo-24()**

Comment: When you say "it is not listening" @Judy, does the program's execution actually get to the start of the method containing the `if`?

Comment: OK, you have an error to debug - cool. The first thing for you to do is to narrow down which variable reference in your code is causing that. Does it supply a line number to help you find out which variable is incorrect? If it is the long `if` we are discussing, then commenting out lines one-by-one (just temporarily) would help a lot.

Comment: yes it does but it ignores the **if**, and jumps to **else** which takes me to frame 12 (try again screen).

Comment: I doubt it has ignored the `if` - it is executing it exactly as you have asked for. Your job is to find out why. Use one of the debugging techniques I have outlined to do this.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "commenting out the lines one-by-one"? No error pops up, it just doesn't execute the if statement.

Comment: See my update @Judy. Also, if you are still getting the error you mentioned above, then please: add that to the bottom of your question by editing it on this page, and explain in your question the circumstances in which it triggers. Do you get it, for example, when you click the Finish button? Or do you only get it if you click the Finish button when all the pieces are in the right place? etc. (You'll find on Stack Overflow there is an expectation that questions are kept up to date, for the benefit of new readers, so they don't have to wade through swathes of comments).

Comment: I've reached the **rightsockmc**.@halfer, All the lines before the **rightsockmc** line, when I would click finish, it would take me to frame 11 (congratulations screen) and even when I purposely misplaced a piece, it would take me to frame 12 (try again screen) until I uncommented that line. I've also double checked each and every target and made sure that the location was correct. The location was even correct on the **rightsockmc** but when I click the finish button, when I've placed the pieces, it goes to the try again screen.

Comment: Alright @Judy, you are on the right lines. What are the values of `rightsockmc.x` and `rightsockmc.y` before the `if` statement is executed? Use a breakpoint or a console output command here (note I don't know how to do that, I don't use AS3). Check that `rightsockmc` is the correct name for this thing - I assume it gets its name from the element settings in your designer GUI.

Comment: I have successfully debugged the problem @halfer, thank you so much, thankyou for sticking by me to the end. It seems the problem was in the code above, I used an incorrect name and an incorrect location.

Comment: Now the problem that still persists is the **TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Ronaldo_fla::MainTimeline/EntFrame()**

Comment: No probs @Judy. OK, so you'll need to find out where in your code that error is triggered. Do you have a line number in the error output? If you get this error in your debug console, I imagine you could output your own debugging statements in order to narrow down the line is causing it (if you cannot get a line number from Flash).

Comment: There is no error number but I think the error is on the line: **function EntFrame(e:Event) :void**. The "e:Event" isn't a constant, but I don't know what will replace it. I copied this bit of coding from a YouTube tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRRV65Lz4J8 at 6:05 I copied the coding but he doesn't explain what it means as it is "complex".

Comment: No, I don't think it's that line @Judy. The error is saying that you are trying to access a property of an object, but that the object is null. The line you've provided there does not try to access an object property (it is just saying that parameter `e` must be of class type `Event`). Is there more information than just the error you have supplied? Flash not providing a line number is quite unlikely, IMO.

Comment: and @halfer, without the "e.Event" the buttons won't work so something needs to go into that parenthesis but it's not that specific line as I have a buttons and the guy in the tutorial didn't.

Comment: here is a picture of the messages being repeated. @halfer http://i.imgur.com/Iz3sf9m.png

Comment: OK @Judy, can you add some console output commands to narrow down where that is being raised?

Comment: What do you mean by "console output commands" @halfer. I am so sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Add in `trace()` commands @Judy - they will appear in your log output to help you narrow down what is causing the error ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885703/as3-trace-click-button)). Put in `trace("a");`, `trace("b");`, `trace("c");` etc in various places of your choosing to understand the program flow. Your task at this stage to work out what line is causing the error. It is likely to have a dot in it (of the form `object.property`).